# Extract with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a little c# program to help me with server administration. When someone is connecting to my server I get following message:

```
Verified GUID (1234567890abcdefghhij) of player #1 playername
```

I want to extract "playername" which can also have special chars and spaces in between like "player name". I tried different approaches with Regex Split but it seems that none of them is really working. My last regex pattern looked like that:

```
string pattern = @"([#]{1}+[1-9]{1,2}+[\s]{1})";
string[] playername = Regex.Split(connectionmsg, pattern);
```

Here I tried to split the string and only use the last part to get the players name but while in an online regex editor this gives me result I want it's not working inside my programm.

Glad for any advice as I'm usually not working with Regex and this stuff freaks me out.

Comment: Try [`string pattern = @"#[1-9]+\s+";`](https://ideone.com/EGjcEY). `playername[1]` will hold the player name.

Comment: I thought about that but as I mentioned the playername can have a space in between, so I would not get the full playername but only the last part of it. It could be "player name" or "pla yer name" and I would only extract "name" then.

Comment: string pattern = @"#[1-9]{1,2}\s";

Comment: That worked out great, thanks :)

Comment: I'd modify this to `@"#[1-9][0-9]\s";`, otherwise it won't work for `#10`. If you want more than 99 potential players, make it `@"#[1-9][0-9]*\s";`

Comment: Your limiting to a # < 100 btw

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, it finally works out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the first `#`, then read from the next white space?

```
string player = msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf(" ", msg.IndexOf("#")) + 1);
```